# Calling function LordRecord() on Page Load wont update data on button click ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ToString())
    If Not Request.Cookies("UsernameCookie") Is Nothing Then
        Dim cookie As String = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies("UsernameCookie").Value)
        Dim acc() As String
        acc = Split(cookie, "=")
        username = acc(1)
        Call LoadRecords()
    Else
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")
    End If
End Sub

    Protected Sub btnSavePD_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    cmd3 = New SqlCommand
    cmd3.CommandText = "Update_Details"
    cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Trim())
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtFirstname.Text)
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtLastname.Text)
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtAddress.Text)

    cmd3.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript([GetType](), "CallMyFunction", "Success();", True)
End Sub
```

There are no errors actually its just that I can't seem to update after button click because calling `LoadRecords()` on Page Load, I tried removing the `Call LoadRecords()` and yes I was able to update. Anyone know how to solve this? I would gladly appreciate it thank you!

Comment: Should I remove the LoadRecords() from my page load? I want to display the data when the page loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please disregard my comment. You should use If Not Page.IsPostBack.

Try this on your Page Load:

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
   LoadRecords() 
End If
```